# CLLocationManager works only once

Tags: swift, macos

I'm new to swift - currently, my current location is only output once in the console when I first call `setupLocationManager()` on init through `override func awakeFromNib()`. When I want it to output my new location by calling `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` when I click a button with the method `updateLocation()`, it prints an error. Any way to fix this? All help is appreciated.

```
import Cocoa
import CoreLocation

class StatusMenuController: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system().statusItem(withLength: NSVariableStatusItemLength)
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
var currentLocation:CLLocation?

@IBAction func quitClicked(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)
}

@IBAction func updateClicked(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    updateLocation()
}

func updateLocation() {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    statusItem.menu = statusMenu
    let icon = NSImage(named: "statusIcon")
    icon?.isTemplate = true
    statusItem.image = icon
    statusItem.menu = statusMenu
    setupLocationManager()
}

func setupLocationManager(){
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager?.delegate = self
    //self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

}

// Below method will provide you current location.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    if currentLocation == nil {
        currentLocation = locations.last
        locationManager?.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        let locationValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

        print(locationValue)

        locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

// Below Method will print error if not able to update location.
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error")
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `if` condition in the code which suspends updating the location after the location is set once (`if currentLocation == nil`). You have to reset `currentLocation` to `nil` before restarting the manager.

```
@IBAction func updateClicked(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
    currentLocation = nil
    updateLocation()
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks! Another issue has come up in the process - sometimes when I call it works, other times its an error - this seems to come up randomly. Perhaps an internet problem? Furthermore, when it does succeed, it prints the location twice or (rarely) four times. Multiple prints on one button click; yet when the app first runs on init it only prints it once. Any possible solution? Much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with CoreLocation